# OpsWorks Node Js Server not working as expected

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

I have Node js server in opeworks, and my code is deploy on S3 service,
when I was update the code and update zip folder in s3, after that I have redeploy the node. JS app in node JS server, but the result after running the code it was show last app result it will not give as expected or as per updated code.